# jQuery strip part of dynamic text, then format to date with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, regex, date, strtotime

I want to strip out everything before the first "- " and everything after the " -" so I am left with "Dec 25, 2011" below (dates are dynamic so it always wont be Dec 25, 2011).  I need to have a Javascript variable first:

Here is the html:

```
<p class="review-rating">
 By oakbarrels
 - Dec 25, 2011
 -
 Something.com
</p>
```

Here is the javascript variable I want to strip out "Dec 25, 2011":

```
var thedate = $(this).find('.review-rating').html();
```

With "Dec 25, 2011" in a variable I would like to now use pHp `strtotime` to format it to "12/25/2011".

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP? You can reformat the date with JavaScript...

Comment: That would be fine, but I am throwing into a MYSQL database, thought it would be easier using php.  The Date is dynamic.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include that information, including the code you're using to retrieve the date from JS and pass into PHP via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date string with Javascript, you can do something like this in jQuery:

```
$('.review-rating').text().match(/\-\s([^\n]+)/)[1].trim();
```

You can see a jsFiddle of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/w2HvA/

Once this date string is passed to PHP you can use the following to format it.

```
echo date("d/n/Y", strtotime($theDateString));
```

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect the new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple explode to start, so something like this:

```
$str = "Your HTML here <p class='review-rating'>....</p>";
$array = explode($str,'-');
$date = trim($array[1]);
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$reformatedDate = date("d/n/Y",$timestamp);
```

You will def need to clean it up and make sure it works, but this should give you the general idea.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
<?php
$atr = '<p class="review-rating">
 By oakbarrels
 - Dec 25, 2011
 -
 Something.com
</p>';
preg_match('/-([^\->]+)-/mis',$atr,$m);
$dateStr = trim($m[1]);
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateStr));
```

Using jQuery:

```
var thedate = $('.review-rating').html();
alert(thedate.split('-')[1])
```